# function SUM not working on CSV file in PHP

Tags: php, csv

its again me. I made my code to tried  to made my code to calculate ID's total SUM
i wrote this code , but the part where i get to echo that $sumArray[$nameEmp] += $itemPacked;
i dont the get total SUM i get again the ID's single numbers . Instead of Total 78 and 155 , i get
the items as the 3rd row.. Where is my mistake ....

Thank you in advance

```
<?php
$row = 1;
if (($handle = fopen("packing.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $row++;
        $startTime          = $data[Start];
        $endTime            =  $data[Finish];
        $itemPacked         = $data[Item];
        $nameEmp            = $data[Employee];
        $startParts         = explode(":", $startTime);
        $endParts           = explode(":", $endTime);
        $startMinute        = (int)$startParts[1];
        $startHour          = (int)$startParts[0];
        $endMinute          = (int)$endParts[1];
        $endHour            = (int)$endParts[0];
        $differenceHour     = ($endHour - $startHour);
        $differenceMinute   = ($endMinute - $startMinute);
        $differenceHour     -= (($differenceMinute < 0) ? 1 : 0);
        if ($differenceMinute < 0) 
            $differenceMinute += 60;

        $difference = $differenceHour * 60 + $differenceMinute;

$sumArray = array();

    if (!isset($sumArray[$nameEmp])) {
        $sumArray[$nameEmp] = 0; // create new entry for nameEmp with balance=0
    
echo  "<br>\n". $sumArray[$nameEmp] += $itemPacked ;// add balance for NameEmp


 $pickedRate = $perMin * $itemPacked;
        $perCal = $pickedRate / $difference *$precentEff;

        echo $nameEmp. "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;" . $itemPacked. "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;" . round($perCal, 0) . "%" . "<br>";
}   

    }
    fclose($handle);

}
?>
```

```
Output 
Total for Each ID  ID  Item picked      Perc
40                 11    40             100%
3                  23   32             80%
26                 11    26             65%
12                 11    12             75%
123                23    123            196%
```

Instead of these output i have , i need Output like this

```
Total for Each ID   ID  Item picked      Perc
                    11    40             100%
                    23   32             80%
                    11    26             65%
78                  11    12             75%
155                 23    123            196%
```

Comment: You're recreating `$sumArray = array();` on every loop. Move that before your while loop. Also of note: You're missing the quotes on your first 4 `$data` keys, and unless it's defined before this loop, `$perMin` and `$precentEff` are not defined.

Comment: And echo-ing this out _inside_ the while loop, probably doesn't make the most sense either.

Comment: @aynber they are defined , this is not the whole code , but when i moved the $sumArray = array(); i dont get the total .

Comment: You're only modifying it if it's not defined. So it will always be equal to the first value.

Comment: now when i moved echo outside the loop and moved the $sumArray = array(); outside the loop before while i get .. the last two is the sum yes , but why i still get the numbers from the 3rd row 
40
32
66
78
155

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. You may have to do a bit of debugging. My favorite thing to do is add echos and/or logging lines along your code to see what it's getting and where

Comment: Agree - this should start with a _proper_ explanation of what these numbers are even supposed to mean. And provide a proper set of input data, that is supposed to lead to the desired output you have shown.